# Shiny: How can I loop thru variable names in the ui selectInput choices in the server datasetInput switch?

Tags: r, shiny, switch-statement

in Shiny I simply want to select which variable of a dataframe shall be plotted and I do not want to have to type all the variable names in the server switch part. Here is what I do:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello World!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("variable", "Choose a variable:",
                  # choices = c("cyl", "mpg")),
                  choices = names(mtcars)),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "BarPlot"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$variable,
           "cyl" = mtcars[,"cyl"],
           "mpg" = mtcars[,"mpg"])
  })
  output$BarPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- datasetInput()
    barplot(table(x))
  })
}
```

Instead of

```
switch(input$variable,
       "cyl" = mtcars[,"cyl"],
       "mpg" = mtcars[,"mpg"])
```

can I do something like

```
choices = mtcars[,get(choices)]
```

to cover all choices without having to type them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use `varSelectInput` and pass the data frame as `data` (it will include all column names as the choices). Then you can extract the selected column from `mtcars` through `mtcars[[input$variable]]` in your example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello World!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      varSelectInput("variable", 
                     "Choose a variable:",
                     data = mtcars),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "BarPlot"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    mtcars[[input$variable]]
  })
  output$BarPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- datasetInput()
    barplot(table(x))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow, that's so easy, thank you very much!